# Going to the parent directory of a file with cd?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, directory

I am writing a .sh to do some work for me, but I am now at the point where I have to cd to the directory the file /path/to/file.end is in.
terminal doesn't allow

```
cd /path/to/file.end
bash: cd: /path/to/file.end: Not a directory
```

there is sadly no workaround I know of, so it would be nice if you could help!

Comment: Um, do you mean `cd /path/to`? That will change the directory to the directory that the file `file.end` is in.

Comment: No, the file is variable, and I would like to enter the path of the file (drop it into the terminal) and then go to the folder it is in

Comment: Related: adding `shopt -s autocd` (default on zsh) to your `~/.bashrc`, *Allows you to cd into directory merely by typing the directory name*. More: `man bash | grep "autocd"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type `cd $( dirname /path/to/file.end)`. That will take you into `/path/to`.

Explanation:

- `dirname` returns the complete path for a file (without the filename, which you would get with `basename`) - i.e. `dirname /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier` returns `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`
- the expression `$(anything)` is replaced by the result of the command in the parentheses. So `cd $( dirname /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier)` is executed as `cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

Another (but old and discouraged) notation for the same was

```
cd `dirname /path/to/file.end`
```

Answer (score 9):

You can not `cd` into a file. Here is a (command line) [function](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3314/bashksh-function-given-a-file-cd-to-the-directory-it-lives) that will automatically `cd` into a path for a given fully qualified file path:

```
function fcd () { [ -f "$1" ] && { cd "$(dirname "$1")"; } || { cd "$1"; } ; pwd; }
```

Comment: Did I get this right?: function fcd () { [ -f $1 ] && { cd $(/file.end $1); } || { cd $1 ; } pwd }
the response is: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `pwd'
it gives me an error this way :(

Comment: @Atsch, need a semicolon before `pwd`, and if you're defining a function in one line, need a semicolon after `pwd`.

Comment: @glennjackman the function just exits without any output or change of dir :(

Comment: run the function, then enter `echo $?` -- what is the exit status?

Comment: darn I should have not doubted myself. The alternative looked better to me when I found it _O-

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something like this - I bump into `bash: cd: Not a directory` more often than I'd like to; this might help. Cheers!

Comment: A more robust version of this function that handles multiple arguments can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59049206/401712 (cd is not commonly used with multiple arguments, but it's still good to support them)

Answer (score 2):

If you append "/.." to the filename that will take you to the correct directory e.g. `cd /path/to/file.end/..`. It works on Cygwin anyway.

Comment: Does not work in bash ;) `touch test && cd /home/test/test/..` says `bash: cd: /home/test/test/..: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does work in windows cmd

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`cd $(dirname $(realpath <path>/myfile.txt))`

It unfolds the path of file.