# How do I navigate up one directory from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, navigation

I can navigate down in directory using `cd` in the terminal. How do I navigate back up if I go too far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Going to the parent directory of a file with cd?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316628/going-to-the-parent-directory-of-a-file-with-cd)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81232/18237 great for working in multiple directory branches, and marking a "starting" point to come back to

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`cd ..` will bring you back exactly one directory up.

You can string together those to go up multiple directories, e.g. up 3

```
cd ../../..
```

Instead of typing `cd ..` multiple times, what you could to is to place the function bellow into your `.bashrc` somewhere at the top, save `.bashrc`, and run `source .bashrc` or just close and reopen a terminal. Now, you have a function that does `cd..` exactly how many times you told it to.

```
function goUp {
  num=$1
  while [ $num -ne 0  ];do
    cd ..
    num=$((num-1))
  done
}
```

Demo:

```
$ cd /usr/share/backgrounds/                                                  

backgrounds:$ goUp 2

usr:$
```

Alternatively:

```
goup(){ 
    cd $(n=$1 awk 'BEGIN{
        for(i=1;i<=ENVIRON["n"];i++) 
            printf "../"}';) 
}
```

Note that such method brings you back along the symlinks. Here's what I mean:

```
$ namei "$PWD" 
f: /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/CentOS
 d /
 d home
 d user
 l VirtualBox VMs -> /mnt/ubuntu/vboxvms
   d /
   d mnt
   d ubuntu
   d vboxvms
 d CentOS

$ goup 2
$ pwd
/home/user
```

#### See also

- [What are directories, if everything on Linux is a file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1073802/295286)
- [Why is the current directory in the ls command identified as linked to itself?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073805/295286)

Comment: Added some more info, check it.

Comment: That could be just `for i in $(seq "$1"); do cd ..; done`.

Comment: @deltab true, could be done as well . . . .But I prefer using while + counter to simulate a for loop. I've asked a relevant question before on U&L site

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple way to go up.

```
cd ../
```

./ means current directory

../means one level up directory

Comment: Upvote because I did not know that the `cd ..` stands for `cd ../`, I thought it would be just like cd.. in Windows and did not understand the space in between until now.

Comment: @questionto42 Yeah, `..` is same as `../`, as well as `.` vs `./`. You can even join multiple slashes like this: `.///`. It's still same as `.`. There are also other `cd` tricks, like `cd -`, which will change the directory to the previous one. But that's a bit off topic :)

Comment: `..`doesn't "stand for `../`, it's just the name of the parent directory.  It's actually an entry (not sure off the top of my head if real or virtual) in the current directory.  Do `ls -la` to see the entries for both `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `popd` and `pushd` too, to "checkpoint" or "bookmark", or as I tend to describe it; "set a spawn-point":

```
pushd ./ # set the spawn point to the current folder ./
```

go to another directory, like `cd ..` or whatever

```
popd     # get back to where we set pushd
```

This is, hopefully something useful for someone,

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and should have been a comment in my opinion

Comment: you are right; in some sense - not directly answering; but as multiple methods should be known - so to speak; not only rely on 1 command; and this is a nice convenient  way (especially for new ones) to do it; good to learn as well (NOTE: only my experience) @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin
**+1 for that comment btw; upvoted! :)**

Comment: Thanks, +1 for yours as well

Answer (score 0):

1. For normal *bash*:

- cd ..
- cd -

2. I suggest using [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) instead of a typical shell. It has a number of aliases; concerning the one you asked, you type `..` without cd. Very comfy.

Next, one may use several periods for more levels:

```
-='cd -'
...=../..
....=../../..
.....=../../../..
......=../../../../..
```

Moreover, for going upward any number of levels, just type the number

```
1='cd -1'
2='cd -2'
3='cd -3'
4='cd -4'
5='cd -5'
6='cd -6'
7='cd -7'
8='cd -8'
9='cd -9'
```

E.g.,

```
$ ~/Documents/Fld1/Fld2/Fld3
$ 3
$ ~/Documents
```